# What change of variables is this?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have come across this integral:
$$\int \frac{f(x+tv)-f(x)}{t}g(x)dx = \int -\frac{g(x)-g(x-tv)}{t}f(x)dx$$

which the author claims is justified by a change of variables, but I cannot see what they did. Would anyone be able to elaborate?

Comment: It's almost replacing $x$ by $x-tv$, but I would expect the integrand to be $\frac{f(x) - f(x-tv)}{t}g(x-tv)$ on the right

Comment: @MPW That was my initial thought, but the author has it as I do in the original post. Here is the link http://www.math.jyu.fi/research/reports/rep100.pdf (top of page 22)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think he is breaking the difference apart and doing a change of variable in one term only, then recombining.

$$\int_{\mathbb R^n}\frac{f(x+tv) - f(x)}{t}\eta(x)\;dx = \int_{\mathbb R^n}\frac{f(x+tv)}{t}\eta(x)\;dx - \int_{\mathbb R^n}\frac{ f(x)}{t}\eta(x)\;dx$$
$$= \int_{\mathbb R^n}\frac{f(x)}{t}\eta(x-tv)\;dx - \int_{\mathbb R^n}\frac{f(x)}{t}\eta(x)\;dx$$
$$= \int_{\mathbb R^n}f(x)\frac{\eta(x-tv)-\eta(x)}{t}\;dx $$

Comment: Such a nice and simple solution! Thank you!

Comment: Note that this only works because the domain of integration is invariant under the change of variable (in this case, translation)

Answer (score 0):

This is only correct in the limit as $t \to 0$ for definite integrals, and that's how it is used in the reference you are giving.

For general indefinite integrals and without the limit it's false. Consider for example the case $f(x) = x, \, g(x) = x^2$. The left hand side does not depend on $t$ in that case, but the right hand side is linear in $t$.

Comment: Thank you, would you be able to elaborate on why it hold for $t \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: As $t \to 0$ it's essentially just integration by parts.